# Update values in new column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to run a package(RAKE) to extract keyphrases from comments(df['CUSTOMER_RECOMMENDATIONS_TRANS]) and create a new column(df['keyphrase_RAKE']) to store them corresponding to each comment. I'm getting an error saying "ValueError: Length of values does not match the length of index".
I know the reason behind the error but don't know how to fix it. What can be done?

keywords return a list of keyphrases.

## This the code:

```html
import RAKE
import operator

# Reka setup with stopword directory
stop_dir = "SmartStoplist.txt"
rake_object = RAKE.Rake(stop_dir)

# Sample text to test RAKE
df = pd.read_excel('my.xlsx')

for i in df['CUSTOMER_RECOMMENDATIONS_TRANS']:
    keywords = rake_object.run(i)
    df['keyphrase_RAKE'] = keywords
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use`pandas.DataFrame.apply` and avoid the for loop

```
df['keyphrase_RAKE'] = df['CUSTOMER_RECOMMENDATIONS_TRANS'].apply(rake_object.run)
```